# Whats the least production build size of basic ionic2 app?

Tags: ionic2

Hello i have clone a basic ionic2 app which has just a component in it.When i tried to get the build of the app using this command `ionic cordova build android` i got an apk file with size 3.9MB then i tried to get the production build using `ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --minSdkVersion=21` the apk file size is now 2.5MB. It is less compared to the previous but is there any way to get the apk file which has much smaller size as i am trying to get the build with minimal setup.Is 2.5MB the least production build size which i can achieve?